# on Andriod Java, is there a way to check if an Application is install on both work and user profile?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know is there a way to check or list down application that are install on both work and user profile programmatically in Android java?

[work profile app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft64O.png) would like to list-down the app programmatically.

Comment: can you please explain more about your requirement?

Comment: I was looking for a sample code that list down work profile and user profile application installed on Andriod devices.